# This Javascript code not working with Python Flask

Tags: javascript, python

**This Javascript code is not working with my Python Flask code**: I don't know, what the problem is, I am also using the library correctly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#name").focusin(function(){
        if(/^[a-z ,.'-]+$/.test($(this).val())){
            $(this).css("border-color", "#37ff00");
        }else{
            $(this).css("border-color", "red");
        }
    });
    $("#er").keyup(function(){
        if(/^[0-9]+$/.test($(this).val())){
            $(this).css("border-color", "green");
        }else{
            $(this).css("border-color", "red");
        }
    });
})
```

**Rendered Template** comes after rendering flask code of python and it's correct I think, but script is not working

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
    <head>
        <link rel= "stylesheet" href= "style.css">
        <script src="script.js" ></script>  
        <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>        
    </head>
    <body>
        <form id="CSI" >

            <label for="er">Enrollment No:</label>
            <input id="er" name="er" type="text">

            <label for="name">Name:</label>
            <input id="name" name="name" type="text">

        </form>
    </body>
<html>
```

**CSS Used**It is used it the form and I want it should be changes

```
#CSI input
{
    padding:5px;
    margin:5px;
    width:200px;
    height:20px;
}
#CSI input:focus
{
    outline:none;
    border-color:blue;

}
```

Comment: What exactly do you  mean, "it's not working"?  What happens? What doesn't happen? Have you checked for errors in the console? ... if `script.js` is your script, then you have to import it **after** importing jQuery.

Comment: Reverse the order of your `<script>` tags - make sure jQuery is first.

Answer (score 0):

As @Pointy points out (no pun inteneded), in order for your script to use jQuery, you need to include jQuery first, and then add your JavaScript files:

```
<script src="jquery.js"></script>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```